# Redis numeric type

Tags: redis

How are numbers usually stored in redis? For example, it seems to support a limited number of scalars, with the primary one being [`string type`](https://redis.io/topics/data-types). Or, are numeric operations just done in the client, i.e., something like:

```
> SET id 4

>>> int(r.get(id)) + ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be memory efficient, Redis has a complex encoding mechanism.

The value of `SET` command is of string type. To save a string in Redis, we need a memory block for the string, and a pointer to the memory block. However if the value can be converted to an integer, Redis will convert the string value to be an integer, and use the pointer to save the integer. So that it can save lots of memory, i.e. no need to allocate an extra memory block the string.

Also Redis preallocates 10000 objects for integer 0 to 9999. If values of keys are between 0 to 9999, Redis will make these keys *SHARE* the value, i.e. a pointer to these preallocated object, instead of creating new object for these keys.

Comment: one (maybe stupid) question -- wouldn't the size of an integer (int32) be smaller than a pointer (8 bytes I'm guessing?) so why would it need to share the value at all? Or maybe the 'value' is just always a pointer, so it doesn't matter (I have no idea about the redis internals)

Comment: The type of integer is of type `long long`, which is 8 bytes, and equal to the size of a pointer on x64 platform. Value is not a single pointer, it's of type `redisObject`.

Comment: I :heart: @for_stack's answers